# random reading by analog inputs of mcp3008

Tags: pi-3, mcp3008

i ran the simpletest.py program for testing the mcp3008 and it is returning random values with 0 value at intervals to the pins left open and also to the pin getting input from MQ-9 sensor...

can anybody point out ....whats wrong in this...?

[image: Here is the circuit diagram i am using]

[image: Here is the snap of the code output]

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008/tree/master/examples

here is the link of the code by adafruit to test mcp3008

but i get 0 and 1023 correctly when i connect the pins to ground and 3.3v respectively

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Connect each of the pins you aren't using to the Agnd pin. That will ensure unused inputs don't get stray signals.

Comment: but i am getting gibberish input in pin 0 too......there sensor is connected.....still.....

Comment: Then your sensor is either wired wrong or broken. You need to read the datasheet. Is Vcc on the sensor connected to Vref is Vdd connected to Agnd? Is it running at the right voltage?

Comment: the circuit is connected exactly as in the circuit diagram